# read file using file descriptor

Tags: c, file

I need to read a file opened like this:

```
int outfile = open(*fileName, "w");
```

using the file descriptor, I'm doing that like this:

```
char txt[50];
int bytes;  
bytes = read(outfile,txt, 50);
```

But I'm getting segmentation fault and the application abort, any ideas?

Comment: `*fileName` looks wrong; it would have to be `char **fileName` to be correct. You also need to use the correct flags for the open, not a string as with `fopen()`. Did you check that `outfile` was a non-negative integer? (You probably want: `int outfile = open(fileName, O_WRONLY); if (outfile < 0) ...deal with error...;`)

Comment: outfile is not negative I'm able to use the same descriptor to write in the file but not to read.

Comment: You won't be able to use a write-only file descriptor for reading.

Comment: If your compiler is not warning you about problems with the call to `open()`, you need to turn up the warning levels on your compiler so that it does.  You also need to include `<fcntl.h>` (as well as `<unistd.h>`) to get the declaration of `open()` and the control flags.  I compile with flags: `gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror` and those would not have let your code through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the second argument to open. It's  "w" this seems like it should indicate that you're opening the file for writing. However, my man pages for [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) indicates that the second argument should be one of: `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`. (fopen uses strings like "w", "w+", "r", ... but that's fopen not open). You may be getting lucky that the value of "w" as an int sets you up for writing but you really want to check your return values and probably want to use

```
open(*filename, O_RDWR);
```

to set up the mode for reading and writing.